# Ошибка 80040e21. Произошли ошибки во время выполнения многошаговой операции OLE DB

Tags: sql-server, vba

Ситуация следующая:
Написал макрос для выгрузки данных из базы SQL Server в Excel. У меня все работает корректно. Отправил файл с макросом коллеге и у него появляется данная ошибка. Отдел безопасности говорит, что доступ ему предоставили.

Строка соединения:
`ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=server name; " _
    & "Initial Catalog=database name; Integrated Security=SSPI; " _
    & "IsolationLevel=adXactReadUncommitted"`

[image: Ошибка 80040e21]

Весь код

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As New ADODB.Recordset, rec2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim vac As String

rec.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rec.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rec2.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rec2.LockType = adLockOptimistic

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Лист1.Unprotect Password:="пароль"
лист2.Unprotect Password:="пароль"

лист1.Activate
лист1.Range("A7:U7").Select
лист1.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents


лист2.Activate
лист2.Range("A7:R7").Select
лист2.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
лист1.Activate

con.Open
rec.Open "SELECT * " & _
"FROM [database].[schema].[table] " & _
"WHERE [UserName] like '" & Application.UserName & "'", con
If rec.RecordCount <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Сообщение" & _
    vbNewLine & "Продолжение сообщения", vbOKOnly
Else
    vac = rec.Fields("Столбец")
    rec.Close
    If vac <> "значение" Then
        rec.Open "SELECT *" & _
        "FROM [database].[schema].[table2]" & _
        "Where [Столбец2] = '" & vac & "'", con
        rec2.Open "SELECT *" & _
        "FROM [database].[schema].[table3]" & _
        "Where [Столбец2] = '" & vac & "'", con
    Else
        rec.Open "SELECT *" & _
        "FROM [database].[schema].[table2]", con
        rec2.Open "SELECT *" & _
        "FROM [database].[schema].[table3]", con
    End If
    Лист1.Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset rec
    Лист2.Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset rec2
    MsgBox "Готово"

End If

Лист1.Protect Password:="Пароль", _
    Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, _
    AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
Лист2.Protect Password:="Пароль", _
    Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, _
    AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
Лист1.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в отсутствии доступа ко всем всем таблицам которые используются в join'ах таблиц table2 и table3.

Comment: Показалось, что всё-таки вполне ответ. Обсудил в чате https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54157215#54157215